# A variable is not getting initialized in ajax call response- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call in a another function `function checkUrl(url){...}`. When this function is called and Ajax request has been sent, and a response is got. I have declared a variable `var str;` inside this `function checkUrl(url){...}`.  function, which is not in the scope of the Ajax function, so it means that variable `str` is global to the Ajax function. What I need is, when I get the response I want to assign that response to that global variable. But due to some reasons the variable is not getting to be initialized and its `return` statement is returning undefined value. When I initially assign an empty string or null value like `var str = null;` or `var str = " ";` then the function `function checkUrl(url){...}`.  returns that value which has been initialized initially. I don't know why its not getting initialized during run time when I get the response.

**My Code**

```js
function checkUrl(url){

   var str;
   $.ajax({
      method:"GET",
      url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?fbPostUrl=true",
      data:{
       url:url
      },
      success:function(r){
       console.log(r);
         switch(r){
          case "not_using_ext":{
           console.log("Script2 Says After Response : User is not using the extension ! ");
           str = "not_using_ext";
           break;
          }
          case "using_ext":{
            console.log("Script2 Says After Response : User is using the extension !");
                 str = "using_ext";
               break;
          }
         }
      }
   });
   alert("Value of str is :  " + str);
   return str;
   
}
```

Comment: The AJAX call is asynchronous, which means that `str` is not set when you return it. See the duplicate question for the pattern you need to use to fix this issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan they have provided the solution for pure javascript, how would I apply that for jquery ajax. They have used this ! 

`function ajax(url) {
 var str;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      str = this.responseText;
      resolve(str);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

ajax("http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/")
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // An error occurred
  });
`

Comment: This answer in the question is using jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/a/21862907/519413